# Volume bounded by $y=x$, $z=x$, $z=0$ and $x+y=2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

I'm having trouble visualizing the domain I am trying to integrate over. May someone help me visualize so that I may set up the double integral. Thanks.

Comment: you might want to check this quick tool http://technology.cpm.org/general/3dgraph/

Comment: you have 4 planes that enclose a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this figure.  The bold lines show were two planes intersect.  Does this help?
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see $z=x$ I rather see $z=y$. (If it is a mistake, then I get it now).

Comment: you are right... here you go.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight rearrangement, you have a tetrahedron with boundary planes: $z=0, z=x$ and $y=x, y=2-x$ .

Thus you wish to integrate $z\in[0;x]$ and $y\in [2-x; 0]$ but where should $x$ lie?

$$\iiint\limits_{\{(x,y,z): x\in[\bbox[white, border:gray 1pt dotted]{\color{white}{~0~;~1~}}], y\in[2-x;x], z\in[0;x]\}}1\operatorname dz\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$